# uA702 OpAmp internal circuit confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I know that i don't have to understand the internals of Op-Amp ic to be able to use it but it's just some curiosity.

Anyway i've found [this file](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee214/ee214.1042/Handouts/ho15opamp.pdf) have some explanation of the ic internals "through the ages".

I came to this very first circuit and there's something i really want to get ,
the document says that Q3 solves the problem of the differential pair and make us get the full gain of the single ended output instead of half of the gain.

This is supposed to be done using Q3 which acts as an OpAmp inside the circuit but i don't get how, and it would be great if somebody explained it to me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the paper explains, Q3 functions as an opamp in over a limited domain of operation in the sense that its output (collector voltage) is a function of the difference between its two inputs (base and emitter). Negative feedback via R1 insures that the base (inverting input) is held at a relatively fixed voltage with respect to the emitter (noninverting input).

This assists the rest of the circuit by making sure that all of the signal voltage variation across R1, which is caused by the current variation in Q1, appears at the upper end of R1 rather than at its lower end, where it is connected to Q1's collector. This means that the signal voltage is also imposed on the upper end of R2, where it can help drive Q4 and the rest of the circuit.

Q3 has essentially the same function as the upper transistor in a [cascode amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode), holding Q1's collector at a fixed voltage, but via a different mechanism.